# Can i use pre-approval using PayPal website payments pro?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am making a system in which user permits pre-approval of amount. I've used pre-approval with chained payment. But the problem is that my customer gets redirected to PayPal site and also he/she must have a PayPal account or need to create one. So can i make pre-approval payment using PayPal website payment pro? So my customers will not get redirected to PayPal account. And the process becomes more fast? Note :- I don't want to use authorization and capture method. Thanks.

**Edit**

One more question :- If i make the website in the UK and the currency in GBP, can I still use the American Paypal account for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth and Capture is what you're asking for, but then you say you don't want it..??  That's what gives you the functionality you're after, though.

You could do a $0 auth and then run DoReferenceTransaction when you're ready to process the payment as opposed to capturing an actual auth if you want.

Those are your only options when working with Pro, though, and it would give you the same sort of preapproval experience for the buyer.

Here are the steps to accomplish what you're after.

1. Use [DoDirectPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) to run a [$0 Authorization (card verification)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/#cardverifications).  Users will enter their credit card details directly into a form on your site without any redirection to PayPal (and without any knowledge PayPal is being used at all unless you notify them some way.)
2. Save the transaction ID that you get form this card verification into your transaction history for the customer in your database.  This ID is what will be used to process future payments using that credit card.
3. When you're ready to process a payment for this customer, pull the ID out of the database and use it with a [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) request to process any amount you need to.

So the card verification is your preapproval, and then running reference transactions are the same as running Pay requests with a Preapproval key.  Both methods accomplish the same thing, but one is with direct credit cards and the other is not.

If you're using PHP you can use this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-sdk) to make all of the API calls very quick and easy for you.  If you're using some other language then there are SDKs available for those as well I'm sure.

Comment: My website is like crowd-funding model. But the problem is i can not authorize site owner due to some reasons. So isn't there any way by which i can provide credit card payment and do pre-approval?

Comment: Reference Transactions are the way you would do it.  That's exactly what they're for.

Comment: Can you please clarify the whole process if possible? And whether my customers will be redirected to PayPal site or not if i follow your way.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrew Angell **Angell EYE** :)

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if i am wrong, @Andrew Angell @Ved Pandya

Auth and Capture or Capture payments later method allows you to do direct payment, but it comes with additional charges, which might not suitable for crowdfunding model as refund/ cancel payment is very frequent

Auth and Capture: You are required to pay $0.30 for each "Card Verification Transactions"

Capture payments later: You are required to pay $0.30 for each "Uncaptured Authorization" that you triggered

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/merchant-fees